# Collection not returning in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I have a view that is populated from a view model with one of the properties being a collection of complex types. The view renders correctly with the list being iterated into a table with a radio button for each item which has not already been selected. When I submit the form I cannot get the list of objects back into the model and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Each item in the collection is added to the view as below:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++
    var rowClass = "selectRow";

    if (item.IsSelected)
    {
        rowClass = "success";
    }


    <tr class="@rowClass">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[i].PropertyOne)
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m =>  m.Items[i].PropertyTwo)
        </td>
        <td class="actions">
            // only those items not previously selected need a radio button
            @if (item.IsSelected == false)
            {
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m =>  m.Items[i].IsSelected,  m.Items[i].PropertyOne, new { id = "IsSelected_" +  m.Items[i].PropertyOne })
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have tried using @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PropertyOne) but I cannot bind the collection of selected values back to the model. I can return everything else in the model using hidden fields but I have no clue how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The best way to figure out what's going on here is to see what `Model.Items` is on the wire when you post.  Have you used Fiddler?  http://www.telerik.com/fiddler.  Or FireBug?

Answer (score 2):

If you want collections to post correctly to the model binder, you cannot use a `foreach` loop (unless you are using `EditorFor`, see comment).  You have to use a good old fashioned `for` loop and have your collection derived from `IList`.  See my question and the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14165632/27457) for more info.

Additionally, any property of the collection object type that you want posted, you need to assure that it is used in the loop.  So, say your `Item` class looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

...your loop might look like this:

```
@for(var i = 0;i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items[i].ItemId)
        <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].Description)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Items[i].IsSelected)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

It's also important to note that simply displaying a model property *will not* post it.  Meaning that...

```
@Model.Items[i].Description
```

...will not post, but hiding it or using it in an HTML element...

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items[i].Description)
```

will post and bind correctly.

One of the definitive articles on this subject from Phil Haack can be found [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Comment: I have looked at this but have been unable to get the view to submit when I change the foreach to a for loop.

Comment: See my edit, and post your revised code with the `for` loop in your original question as an edit so we can see what you've got.

Comment: hi @AJ, your answer is correct. One thing is it doesn't have to use `for`, you still can use foreach. take a look this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842935/asp-net-mvc-complex-model-updating/20843172#20843172

Comment: @Lin - Thanks, I didn't know that `EditorFor` would handle a `foreach` across the wire.

Comment: @crunchy - I don't believe `DisplayFor` will bind, and other than the missing right paranthesis in the `for` loop, your code looks OK.  Have you Fiddled it to see what's getting posted?